# Flink1.5.4 exception: Corrupt stream, found tag: 105

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

My program wants to join two streams without Flink Window.

I connect two streams and define a class A extends RichCoFlatMapFunction to handle them. 
In class A, I use a Guava cache to hold all the data from flatmap1/2 method, and join them by a tag from streams. 
Then Guava cache has a remove listener to collect joined&expired data to next Flink Function.

```
private synchronized void collect(ReqFeatures features) {
    feaCollector.collect(features);
}
```

Each time at the beginning, it runs well, but a few hours later, it's always dead because of this exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Corrupt stream, found tag: 105
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.streamrecord.StreamElementSerializer.deserialize(StreamElementSerializer.java:220)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.streamrecord.StreamElementSerializer.deserialize(StreamElementSerializer.java:49)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.plugable.NonReusingDeserializationDelegate.read(NonReusingDeserializationDelegate.java:55)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.serialization.SpillingAdaptiveSpanningRecordDeserializer.getNextRecord(SpillingAdaptiveSpanningRecordDeserializer.java:106)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor.processInput(StreamInputProcessor.java:172)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask.run(OneInputStreamTask.java:104)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:306)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:712)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And sometimes there's another error log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: When there are multiple buffers, an unfinished bufferConsumer can not be at the head of the buffers queue.
at org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:195)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.PipelinedSubpartition.pollBuffer(PipelinedSubpartition.java:158)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.PipelinedSubpartitionView.getNextBuffer(PipelinedSubpartitionView.java:51)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.consumer.LocalInputChannel.getNextBuffer(LocalInputChannel.java:186)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.consumer.SingleInputGate.getNextBufferOrEvent(SingleInputGate.java:551)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.consumer.SingleInputGate.getNextBufferOrEvent(SingleInputGate.java:508)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.BarrierTracker.getNextNonBlocked(BarrierTracker.java:94)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor.processInput(StreamInputProcessor.java:209)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask.run(OneInputStreamTask.java:104)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:306)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:712)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If I use Flink Window Function instead, this exception doesn't occur.
Why does this exception occur, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this also happens in Flink 1.9.1 (albeit for us, it happens when we run `flink stop <job-id>`)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same problem with getting checkpointing lock while collecting output. The users flatMap function already hold the checkpointing lock, so if u collect output in flatMap function could also fix this problem.

in flink's code:

```
synchronized (checkpointingLock) {
                numRecordsIn.inc();
                streamOperator.setKeyContextElement1(record);
                streamOperator.processElement(record);
            }
```